# Running JavaMail on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, jakarta-mail

I am trying to sending email though JavaMail using Tomcat. In oracle, it asks me download it from https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home, but which jar files do I need? I am also using maven.

I am trying to follow these examples(http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm).

I appreciate if someone could help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just need the javax.mail.jar and you can use any of the classes that are included in that JAR.

The others are just some text files with some addition notes. You might need to look at these later on if you come to use SSL etc so they might be worth downloading but just the JAR is all you need.

Then you need to import the JAR into your build path and you should be able to access all of the functionality that you need.

Comment: Yes, and if you're using maven you can use the groupid and artifactid for that jar file listed in the table on that page.

Comment: Didn't quite get why the OP bothers downloading files if he/she is using Maven anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven you don't need to download anything. Just add the below XML to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

in the `<dependencies>` section.